# my processes number of voluntary context switches are continuously increasing, what can be the cause and a proper solution for that

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

I have a process in which voluntary context switches are continuously increasing, what can be the cause and a proper solution for that ?

also nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches are remaining the same.

Answer (score 0):

- A context switch can be voluntary - where a process either completes
     its task before its allotted time slice is over or enters a
     suspended state because it makes a blocking IO call.

  Alternatively a context switch can be involuntary wherein if a
  process exhausts the cpu time slice allotted to it the kernel will
     pre-empt the process and switch it out to grant cpu time to another
     process in the run queue.

  So From above two staement conclusions can be made easily given some one know process behaviour very well